# App will not display on emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am programming an app using a tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-k5gwz_91o), and when I run the app on the emulator, the app does not run on the virtual android. I am using Nexus 5 API 23. 
This is my import code: 
package com.example.isabelbolger.firstapp;

```
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

I don't know why my app will not show on the emulator, maybe I have to click something in the phone to launch the app? I am totally new to android studio. Thank you
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Developer Options and USB debugging on emulator?

If you haven't already, do the following:

Open Settings in emulator -> About phone -> Find Build Number.

Then tap “Build number” seven times to enable Developer Options.

Go back to Settings menu and now you'll be able to see “Developer options” there.

Tap it and turn on USB Debugging from the menu on the next screen.

Then try to run your app.